# Cannot initialise a large 2d array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I haven't used C for ever, and now I need to initialize a large 2d array to do some computation.

I get an error `First-chance exception at 0x003717B7 in Project1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00382000).`

And this line is the cause, but only when indexed are large, 500 is the highest I must use. The highest index I can initialise is 356.

```
double b[500][500];
```

How can I compile this? I'm compiling from VS 2013.

Code I must run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    #define ROWCOL 356

    int i, j;

    double column_sum[ROWCOL];
    double b[ROWCOL][ROWCOL];

    for (i = 0; i < ROWCOL; i++) {
        column_sum[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ROWCOL; j++) {
            column_sum[i] += b[j][i];
        }
    }

    printf("Press any key to close...\n");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Move the declaration outside of main(){...}.

Comment: windows (un)surprisingly has a very small stack for each process... works fine in linux though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making it static to move the storage from stack to global storage:

```
static double b[ROWCOL][ROWCOL];
```

Moving the definition outside `main` does the similar thing but would introduce the name `b` into the file namespace.

Also you could try allocating the space dynamically, with which the storage would be on the heap:

```
double (*b)[ROWCOL] = malloc(sizeof(double) * ROWCOL * ROWCOL);
/* ... */
free(b);
```

Comment: Quick question, I would use this to have tests done in a loop. I know that in array declaration, the value must be constant. But is there a way to instead of declaring ROWCOL, having it dynamic anyway?

Comment: @HelpNeeder In C99 or later the variable length array is supported and you could use something like `int a; int b[a];` so it's doable. For C89 and earlier the GCC supports it through a GNU extension.